# Completely flat/flush recessed lighting trim

Tags: lighting, drywall, ceiling, trim, recessed-lighting

I can't seem to find these anywhere, but I really want a trim that is completely flush with the ceiling (at the mud level) for my 4" recessed cans. That is, I don't want the trim to have any profile that extends below the ceiling.

Does anyone know is something like this exists?

Comment: It does, I have used them before. I will look them up. Edison makes a brand, but there is another that does the job real nice. I hope it is still available. I did know the name of it then, sadly still don't.

Comment: I forgot to mention, it starts with the rough in kit, so If you already have the rough ins installed, you pretty much will have to contrive something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing the trim does typically is hide the edge of the drywall which usually, one would not want to look at because it's rough and ugly.

It's hard to imagine trim that doesn't extend (at least the thickness of the metal itself) below the surface of the ceiling.

If you want a trimless look, what you will probably need to do is apply drywall compound up inside the can itself a bit, and cover the edge between the can and the drywall.  Then carefully hand-sand that edge into the shape you want.  Don't forget to protect the light socket by deenergizing it and  stuffing some non-conductive plastic into it during this work.  When done, re-paint the ceiling, and paint up into the can as well.  Either use paint that can handle the heat of the bulb or commit to using LED bulbs only.

Comment: Yeah, I realised after painting, that if I want trimless, I'd probably need to re-mud and paint. I was maybe hoping that if I cut a perfectly circular hole, there was some spring loaded solution that would be snug. Ah well, I guess I just need to find a good looking trim.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this done.  There is no special trim.

Steps:

- Install trim
- Take a utility knife and scribe around the trim exactly.
- take out enough drywall layer to set trim - some guys just take off the paper
- mud and sand where needed after reinstalling flush trim

Does it look better?  Debatable.  Is it worth it?  Almost in all cases no.

Note: My opinion above is that of a joe-average drywall/mudder.  I am in no form an expert and I have a crew I hire for high end jobs.  I am sure that my crew could make the trim look perfect in a ceiling.  Also you would probably have to get more expensive trim pieces as most of the cheap ones are grooved and wouldn't look right for this install.

Answer (score 0):

Google "trimless recessed lighting" You will find a number of options for baffles that get installed during taping/mudding. They aren't cheap though! Looks like they are around $55 per trim.